# Odd FileNotFoundException for StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#-4.0, nuget-package, stackexchange.redis

We are using the latest version of StackExchange.Redis, `StackExchange.Redis.1.1.603`. It worked fine for a short while, but I am now getting the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'StackExchange.Redis, Version=1.0.316.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This is strange because there has been no release of this nuget package with that version number. Sometimes a clean build and a restart of Visual Studio 2013 will make it go away, sometimes not. I have removed the reference and reinstalled the nuget package but nothing seems to nuke this issue. Can anyone give any advice on this?

EDIT: This issue was caused by Visual Studio not copying the DLL from the referenced caching library to the website project's `bin` folder.

The odd version number is what threw me. If anyone can answer that I would be interested.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue was caused by Visual Studio not copying the DLL from the referenced caching library to the website project's bin folder.

I am not sure where the version number 1.0.316.0 came from, as this was never a released version.

Comment: If that is indeed the problem then how do you fix it?

Comment: Set Copy Local to `true` in the reference properties.

Comment: The answer is not a solution, is the same problem. more than that, CopyLocal is already set to true in my case

Comment: Being this is over two and a half years ago I don't really remember it all, but the local copy solved the issue for me. If it doesn't help you I recommend asking a new question - I no longer work with .NET.